# Fargate containers intermittently fail due to S3 environment files timeout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-fargate, aws-step-functions

I am currently using a Stepfunction to orchestrate some tasks being run some of which are on AWS Fargate. The Fargate tasks require environment variables that we store in S3 and most of the time it runs fine but I have a low failure rate (>0.1%) where a single fargate task fails with the message:

`"ResourceInitializationError: failed to download env files: file download command: non empty error stream: RequestCanceled: request context canceled caused by: context deadline exceeded"`

Has any one seen this message before and does any one know the cause ?

Comment: I don't have the rep to make a comment. I'm seeing the same error when creating a Fargate Service on ECS using CDK and pulling an env file from S3. It works just fine if I create the ECS service by hand in the console, but I can't see where what I'm doing in CDK is producing different results. The task role and execution role are identical.

Answer (score 0):

My task's VPC had a private subnet set up without a NAT Gateway, so it couldn't access the S3 bucket. After creating a NAT Gateway and adding a new route to the existing routing table for the NAT Gateway, the issue was resolved.

I hope it helps someone who faces same issues.

This is the answer I saw on another post, honestly it worked on my problem. Look at your route table, I set my destination to `0.0.0.0/0`. The person before me had it on `0.0.0.0/8` ... so that was my problem. I hope it helps you.